# Program crashing when attempting to convert array into a string with null character

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm filling an array with 40 pseudo-random capital letters and then converting the array into a string by terminating it with a null character at the 41st element, but my program crashes when I do the latter. Here is the code:

```
char s1[41];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 41; i++)
{
    s1[i] = ((rand() % 26) + 'A');
}
s1[i] = '\0';

puts(s1);
```

The program runs just fine if I print out each character in the array one at a time without the null assignment statement, but everything fails when the null assignment is included. I am required to convert the array into a string and then use the puts function.  Why is this happening? Is a string not simply an array of characters terminated with a '\0' (null)? What is causing this? Is this a compiler error? Attached is a screenshot of the error message.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013, if it matters.

Comment: Off by one. You are writing right behind the array, to `s1[41]`.

Comment: `i < 41` --> `i < 40`

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to look into random number generation. (rand() % 26) = veeery bad.

Comment: You're lucky this program crashes. If it hadn't, this bug might have gone unnoticed for a long time!

Comment: why are you assigning `\0` at the end? I don't think that's required. That's supposed to be there by default.

Comment: Please realize: Ranges in C/C++ are usually [inclusive, exclusive), where the exclusive value is equal to the size (if inclusive is zero). Accessing (dereferencing) an exclusive element leads to undefined behavior (a fast crash is a nice undefined behavior)

Comment: @gldraphael He does that to nul terminate the string, it isn't there by default unless s1 had static storage duration.

Comment: @nos thanks, i never knew that

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the comments, if it's not obvious to you: `i==41` after exiting the loop, so `s1[i]` is writing outside the bounds of the array. This is undefined behavior and, as mentioned, you're lucky it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that I was assigning the null character to a location outside of the array. I needed to decrement i.

Comment: No: make it `char s1[41 + 1];`

Comment: Don't decrement `i`, change your loop limit. `for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)` will write your 40 values (i.e. indexes `0-39`, then the `41`st value goes in `s[i] = 0;` where `i` is `40`.

Answer (score 0):

Make 41 to 40 then try again

```
i < 40
```

Usually trial and error with this number can give you different results

```
   char s1[41];
int i;



for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    s1[i] = ((rand() % 26) + 'A');
}
s1[i] = '\0';

puts(s1);
```